# How to switch from Qt4 MVC to Gtk MVC?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, gtk

I've used Qt for some time and now I want to try Gtk. I want to write simple database application, but it looks like there is no support for sql (I'm forced to fill manually model with data). In Qt we have QSqlQueryModel and QSqlTableModel, QTableView and QTreeView. Gtk approach is more like QTableWidget and QTreeWidget. I need somehow connect to the database, get data and fill the model. Ok, but what if my table is really big? How can I implement in-place editing (Gtk model can't modify data)? Can I chain models to provide filtering like QSortFilterProxyModel? These are basic things that I use all the time writing database applications with Qt. How this can be done with Gtk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GTK+ is more modularized than Qt, so you'll need to look up your requirements in the GObject ecosystem. [libgda](http://www.gnome-db.org/) is what you are looking for.

[Here](http://developer.gnome.org/) is a non-exhaustive overview of the platform for future references.

Comment: What are meaning that GTK+ ir more modularized than Qt? can you explain it more?

Comment: @Khajavi: it means the stuff you usually find in stock Qt it is spread in different libraries in the GTK+ ecosystem. Follow the links provided in the answer for further details.

Comment: Uhum, I got it. I think it is one of the power of GTK+ over Qt, isn't that? I think in Qt we can't extend and use external libraries like GTK+?

Comment: It is just a different approach: in GTK+ if you want SQL support you must install libgda, in Qt you must rebuild Qt. Just as an example, on my dist GTK+ 3.6.4 is 7 Mb while Qt 4.8.4 is 20 Mb.

Answer (score 0):

GTK literally stands for GIMP Toolkit. It's pretty much a purely graphically set of tools for developing GUI applications, Qt on the other hand is a graphics and a whole other stack on top for databases and so on. Your best starting point is working out what DB you're going to use, then getting the development package (if it has C++ bindings), and go through the API docs for it and you'll mostly be building the functionality on your own. There's other database abstraction layers out there, so that's another route you could take.